# How to change the type of join based on condition in mysql?

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT m.id, u.first_name AS otherUser
FROM matches AS m
IF (u.id=m.user2ID)
    Inner JOIN users AS u ON u.id = m.user1ID
ELSE
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = m.user2ID
ENDIF
WHERE m.user1ID=2 OR m.user2ID=2
```

Now my intention is to change the type of join based on condition. Can i do that? If yes then how?

**Update:-**  What i am trying to achieve here is, change the type of join when a certain condition is true like:

```
if(a==1){
  Then do inner join
}else{
 Then do left join
}
```

Comment: you can't change the tpye of join

Comment: isn't there a workaround to do that?

Comment: could be I  take a look

Comment: Roy, what problem are you actually trying to solve. Don't comment. Just adjust your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If this could be euivalent

```
SELECT m.id, u.first_name AS otherUser
FROM matches AS m
LEFT JOIN users  as u  
   ON ( (u.id=m.user2ID AND ON u.id = m.user1ID ) OR u.id = m.user2ID )
WHERE m.user1ID=2 OR m.user2ID=2
```